# Replay last request with RxSwift

Tags: swift, networking, rx-swift

I'm creating a networking layer where I inject API provider and call event to the initialize method.

```
class NetworkingLayer<T: Decodable, E: TargetType> {

    var response: Driver<T>

    init(provider: MoyaProvider<E>, request: Singal<E>) {

        let requestState = request
            .flatMapLatest({
                provider.rx.request($0).map(Respose<T>.self)
                    .map { ReqestState.loaded($0) }
                    .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error  in
                        return Driver.just(.error(error))
                    })
                    .startWith(.loading)
            })
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { fatalError($0.localizedDescription) })

        response = requestState
            .map({ $0.data?.data })
            .filterNil()

    }
}
```

Using them in the following way:

```
class ViewModel {

    let networking: DataNetworkingResponse<[TagItem], ScoutEnpoint>

    init(provider: MoyaProvider<Endpoint>, event: Singal<[Int]>) {

        let request = event
            .map({ Endpoint.getNewItems(prevItemsIds: $0) })

        self.networking = NetworkingLayer(provider: provider, request: request)
    }
}
```

All working like charm. But now I have to implement refresh feature. Refresh my last request. I've added this `let refresh: Signal<()> = Signal.empty()` property to my network layer. But can't understand how to save my last request.

```
class NetworkingLayer<T: Decodable, E: TargetType> {

    let refresh: BehaviorRelay<()> = BehaviorRelay.init(value: ())
    ...
}
```

How can I implement refreshing like this?

```
viewModel.networking.refresh.accept(())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `BehaviorRelay` is a bad idea because it emits a value as soon as it's subscribed to. This means that your `NetworkingLayer` object would make a request as soon as it's constructed.

Better would be to pass another Signal into the `init` method:

```
init(provider: MoyaProvider<E>, request: Singal<E>, refresh: Signal<Void>)
```

I don't know Moya but here's how I would have written something like that using URLSession:

```
enum RequestState<T> {
    case loaded(T)
    case error(Error)
    case loading
}

class NetworkingLayer<T: Decodable> {

    let response: Driver<RequestState<T>>

    init(request: Signal<URLRequest>, refresh: Signal<Void>, provider: URLSession = URLSession.shared, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
        response = Observable.merge(request.asObservable(), refresh.withLatestFrom(request).asObservable())
            .flatMapLatest { request in
                provider.rx.data(request: request)
                    .map { try decoder.decode(T.self, from: $0) }
                    .map { RequestState.loaded($0) }
                    .startWith(.loading)
                    .catchError { Observable<RequestState<T>>.just(.error($0)) }
            }
            .share(replay: 1)
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { fatalError($0.localizedDescription) })
    }
}
```

I threw the `share(replay:)` on there so that subsequent subscribers won't make separate network requests, and I made the decoder injectable so the caller can configure it how they want.

Comment: Thank you for your response!!! Again I'm faced with another problem. I added new `case startLoading` to the enum `RequestState<T>` and would like to use it before the request starts loading. Because when no internet connection or request timeout unable to handle `.loading` event.